# How to set variables using terragrunt before_hook

Tags: bash, terraform, terragrunt

I need to use some gcloud commands in order to create a Redis instance on GCP as terraform does not support some options that I need.

I'm trying this:

```
terraform {
  # Before apply, run script.
  before_hook "create_redis_script" {
    commands     = ["apply"]
    execute  = ["REDIS_REGION=${local.module_vars.redis_region}", "REDIS_PROJECT=${local.module_vars.redis_project}", "REDIS_VPC=${local.module_vars.redis_vpc}", "REDIS_PREFIX_LENGHT=${local.module_vars.redis_prefix_lenght}", "REDIS_RESERVED_RANGE_NAME=${local.module_vars.redis_reserved_range_name}", "REDIS_RANGE_DESCRIPTION=${local.module_vars.redis_range_description}", "REDIS_NAME=${local.module_vars.redis_name}", "REDIS_SIZE=${local.module_vars.redis_size}", "REDIS_ZONE=${local.module_vars.redis_zone}", "REDIS_ALT_ZONE=${local.module_vars.redis_alt_zone}", "REDIS_VERSION=${local.module_vars.redis_version}", "bash", "../../../scripts/create-redis-instance.sh"]
  }
```

The script is like this:

```
echo "[+]Creating IP Allocation Automatically using <$REDIS_VPC-network\/$REDIS_PREFIX_LENGHT>"
gcloud compute addresses create $REDIS_RESERVED_RANGE_NAME \
    --global \
    --purpose=VPC_PEERING \
    --prefix-lenght=$REDIS_PREFIX_LENGHT \
    --description=$REDIS_RANGE_DESCRIPTION \
    --network=$REDIS_VPC
```

The error I get is:

```
terragrunt apply
5b35d0bf15d0a0d61b303ed32556b85417e2317f
5b35d0bf15d0a0d61b303ed32556b85417e2317f
5b35d0bf15d0a0d61b303ed32556b85417e2317f
ERRO[0002] Hit multiple errors:
Hit multiple errors:
exec: "REDIS_REGION=us-east1": executable file not found in $PATH 
ERRO[0002] Unable to determine underlying exit code, so Terragrunt will exit with error code 1
```

Comment: I was running into the same error. You could trying something like
`execute  = ["env",  "REDIS_REGION=${local.module_vars.redis_region}" ...]`. The `env` command will set the env variable...

In my case I wasn't getting any errors but the env variable was still not getting set.. So, instead of doing this in the `before_hook` I did it in `.envrc` (see https://direnv.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same issue and resigned myself to pass the values as parameters instead of environment variables.

It involves to modify the script and is a far less clearer declaration, but it works :|